# What genre is the song "Here Comes a Thought" from Steven Universe?

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

I like the style of the song and I would like to hear more music of that style!

Here is the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rds7V5Sxu-4

Answer (score 2):

This is probably closest to **[Neo-Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_soul)** (which is a sub-genre of @Bebs's suggestion of contemporary R&B).

> Neo soul is a genre of popular music. The term was coined by music industry entrepreneur Kedar Massenburg during the late 1990s to market and describe a style of music that emerged from soul and contemporary R&B. Heavily based in soul music, neo soul is distinguished by a less conventional sound than its contemporary R&B counterpart, with incorporated elements ranging from jazz, funk, hip hop and electronic to pop, fusion, and African music. It has been noted by music writers for its traditional R&B influences, conscious-driven lyrics, and strong female presence.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_soul

Compare these neo-soul classics by female vocalists:

Jill Scott - [Golden](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QCXr79Rkcw)
Angie Stone -  [No More Rain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgG0Hu_FeiA)
Lauryn Hill - [Sweetest Thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-Co5Kz2LuI)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [**Contemporary R&B**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_R%26B), sometimes simply called R&B (that must be distinguished with Rhythm and Blues).

This song has electronic hip-hop-like drums, jazzy keyboards and smooth vocals.

The Wikipedia article above will give you a lot of R&B artists, such as Michael Jackson, Janet Jackson, R.Kelly, Usher, Mariah Carey...