# What's the music genre of "Melting Ice Icream - Twice"?

Tags: identify-this-genre, pop

Most of the result i got from searching is only KPOP genre and it is so obvious. I want another genre result for this song based on maybe its melody, rhythm, or something else. Genre that comes to my head after listening to this song is maybe jazz, but Im not sure what kind of jazz is this.

Here i provide you the music
[TWICE (트와이스)- Melting (녹아요)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5v_6zWW2rFg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on late 90's American R & B, specifically **Neo-Soul**

> Neo soul is a genre of popular music. The term was coined by music industry entrepreneur Kedar Massenburg during the late 1990s to market and describe a style of music that emerged from soul and contemporary R&B. Heavily based in soul music, neo soul is distinguished by a less conventional sound than its contemporary R&B counterpart, with incorporated elements ranging from jazz, funk, hip hop and electronic to pop, fusion, and African music. It has been noted by music writers for its traditional R&B influences, conscious-driven lyrics, and strong female presence.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_soul).

Neo-soul has some of the feel and style of classic 70s soul music, but with more of 90s instruments and beats, and some subtle hip-hop influence.  The intro is the dead giveaway --those sounds effects are pure 90s R & B.  The electric piano is very 70s soul, but the drum-machine beat brings it into the 90s.

See also [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6139/what-genre-is-the-song-here-comes-a-thought-from-steven-universe/6252#6252), and compare this classic Neo-Soul song by [Angie Stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgG0Hu_FeiA).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im looking forward to it.